# Why Google Analytics Audience overview shows more users than sessions?

Tags: session, google-analytics

[image]

Hello everyone,

How come number of users is higher that number of sessions in Google Analytics audience overview report? I know this might be an issue when using pageview level dimension. However, this is not the case in my situation.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2934985?hl=en

Thans for your help!

Comment: Please check this older answer to the same question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/87323

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me when I Set a event like a push impression, so I Has a user without a session.

Best

Mariana Alves